# Type cast class conforming to sub-protocol to parent-protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm having a hard time getting an `MKMapView` subclass to work:

The subclass provides a clustering functionality. Because annotations are being moved to a cluster with a nice animation, the annotations provided to the map must have a setter for `coordinate`. Hence, I've created a 'sub-protocol' of `MKAnnotation`:

```
protocol MyAnnotationProtocol: MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get set }
}
```

So internally the subclass of `MKMapView` works with objects conforming to `MyAnnotationProtocol`.

The clustering algorithm itself is outsourced to another class. For the sake of reusability, the algorithm itself works with `MKAnnotation` objects - no need to provide `MyAnnotationProtocol` objects.

The concrete class I'm providing as annotations to the map looks like this:

```
class MXPointAnnotation: NSObject, MyAnnotationProtocol {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    override init() {
        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    }
}
```

When running, the app crashes at this line inside the cluster algorithm class:

```
let seeds = regionQueryForAnnotation(annotation as! MKAnnotation, inMapView: mapView)
```

`annotation` is stored in an `NSSet` -  therefore it has to be cast before it can be used.

The log says:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSKVONotifying_********.MXPointAnnotation' (0x13402cf40) to 'MKAnnotation' (0x1a1d89ec8).
```

******** is my apps name.

This seems like a bug to me, because clearly `MXPointAnnotation` conforms to `MyAnnotationProtocol` and therefore to `MKAnnotation`?

What really drives me crazy is the fact that when I'm changing the interface of `MXPointAnnotation` to:

```
class MXPointAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation, MyAnnotationProtocol {
....
}
```

the app does NOT crash and everything works as expected.
Note that the protocol conformance is redundant for `MKAnnotation`, because `MyAnnotationProtocol` already conforms to that.
Is this a current Swift bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: just a guess: why do you need NSObject? can you remove that?

Comment: its just the inheritance from nsobject. this shouldn't make any difference?